# What's the easiest way to isolate/scope all SCSS styles for an Angular [Elements] widget?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular7

I have an Angular 7 elements widget that I later embed within a bigger application. When I test the widget in isolation all the styles work correctly as it is accessing styles per component and global styles in `assets/styles/global.scss`. When I embed the widget within the target final application I get a lot of style clashes and the styles of both the application and the widget break.

I tried to simply wrap all styles component and global in my widget wrapping them in a class `.ba` i.e. a short hand for `book-appointment` e.g.

I wrap my appointment wizard scss component with `.ba`:

```
.ba {
    .appointment-wizard-title {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    ...
}
```

I wrap my global scss with `.ba`:

```
.ba {
    h1,
    h2 {
        font-size: 38px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    body {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .input-group {
      position: relative;
      display: table;
      border-collapse: separate;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I wrap my widget into a div with the `ba` class:

```
<div class="ba">
    <app-root></app-root>
</div>
```

When I test the widget in isolation with `ng serve` this works partially but a lot of style details are lost. I lack the way to specify that all the styles should only apply to elements and classes that exist under a `div` classed `ba` ... how do  I that?

Comment: in which SCSS file your code doesn't work properly?

Comment: @KhashayarPakkhesal a mix of things stop working e.g. the background color, the font styles, the layout etc. Some styles work and some don't when I wrap all the SCSS into a base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ba">
    <app-root></app-root>
</div>
```

seems to wrap the whole application. If you have a widget component you could.

Alt1. use a local styles to that component only. It will only exist within the component. ex:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: 'my-component.html',
  styles: ['my-component.scss']
})
```

Alt2. use the class 'ba' closer to the widget. By using host binding decorator in your widget component. Keep your styles global

```
@HostBinding('class.ba') someField: boolean = true;
```

Note. Even if Alt1 seems tempting you need to look out for heavy imports of other sass-files. You can end up duplicating your CSS files in the dist

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I am doing something wrong but doesn't work, the styles are only applied when I use the global scss. Kudos for showing the `HostBinding` feature!